# cordova push plugin MismatchSenderId when send with php

Tags: php, cordova, firebase, push

I install cordova and add the latest offiical push plugin v2x.
I use phonegap desktop app to run the cordova project
and I successfully get the registration token from phonegap developer android app.

I can send with window cmd command, the developer app can receive the push message, but when I send with php, it shows the error bellow?

```
{"multicast_id":7703228532457629637,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

I test with firebase console too, can't received too

Please help I am newbies in cordova

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now is can, cannot use the phonegap developer app to receive notice from eg php post, maybe this developer app can receive via cmd only
must use emulator or real apk and can receive it